# What is the benefit of Aquatic Helms over regular ones?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In playing Guild Wars 2 so far, I've only come across standard helms by way of the Trading Post. However, the filters also let you choose Aquatic Helms. When I first found this, there were none for my level. I figured it let you breath underwater for when I arrived at an underwater zone.

This doesn't exactly seem to be the case, as I can stay underwater seemingly indefinitely in the starter zone I'm in.

**What is the benefit of an Aquatic Helm over a standard one?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to Matthew Scharley's answer, **Aquatic Helms** have their own separate slot along with your aquatic weapons.

Any stats on your regular helm will be void, taking only the stats of your rebreather (Aquatic Helm) whilst underwater.

Answer (score 6):

Aquatic helms are exactly as you suspected a way to stay underwater indefinitely. However all characters start with one, hence it's assumed that you will have at least a basic one at all times and there is no 'breath bar' in Guild Wars 2. Note, if you unequip your aquatic helm then you will still be able to breath under water, but you will have no helm equipped while underwater either.